# Access selected values from html multiselect with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

This is my multiselect form HTML

`<select id="designation" name="designation" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese" >Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes" >Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella" >Mozzarella</option>
</select>`

Here is how I'm trying to access the selected values with js.

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#designation').multiselect();
    var selectedValues = $('#designation').val();
    });`

`selectedValue` is always assigned `nul` by `$('#designation').val()`

How can I fix this ?

I have also tried 
`$("select.designation option:selected").val();`

Comment: You are missing `#` for the ID selector!

Comment: instead of $('designation').val() it should be $('#designation').val() ...you missed '#'

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add it while posting the question. It returns null even when the identifier is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You multiselect will initially be null when the page loads, which is what your code is showing. The code below will update the variable selectedValues whenever you click away the multiselect box.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#designation').click(function() {
            var selectedValues = $('#designation').val();
        });
    }
);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/83brpjav/

Comment: Yeah, it's assigned as null when the page loads. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.multiselect("getChecked")` method returns all selected `check boxes`

**Try this -**

For single selection-

```
var value = $('#designation').multiselect("getChecked").val();
console.log(value);
```

For multiple selection -

```
 var values =  $('#designation').multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
           return this.value;    
        }).get();//return you the all selected values as an array

 console.log(values);
```